# HorizontalScrollView layout param

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I want to use Horizontal GridView in the project. So I have LinearLayout called root.To use Horizontal GridView, i also need HorizontalScrollView.

```
-LinearLayout
   -HorizontalScrollView
      -GridView(Horizontal)
```

so i add (HorizontalScrollView) to root(LinearLayout) and then add GridView to HorizontalScrollView.GridView 's width will be ( no of item * grid view 's column width).The problem is HorizontalScrollView LayoutParam cannot set.I got the test result by adding the background color to each Layouts.
I want the GridView that horizontally scroll.I cannot set the Layout via xml because HorizontalScrollView and GridView are created manually due to show their Category.

Answer (score 1):

Use `recyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager()`.

The GridLayoutManager has the following Constructor:

`GridLayoutManager (Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)`

As you can see you can pass an int for the orientation. One possible option is HORIZONTAL. You can look at the official documentation for more.

More here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html